# Can $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] value be same for 2 different users?

Tags: php, http-headers, user-agent, server-variables

I am asking a basic question.

Can $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] be same for two different systems if the user does not modify the header information which will be set by the browser?

Comment: Sounds like XY problem. Is your actual question _"How can I uniquely identify a client machine"_?

Comment: That is what i am working on. But i don't want answer for that because  that question is already answered many times in stack overflow. i needed to understand the above server variable properly.

Comment: I'm just trying to guess whether your next question will be _"How can I get the client's MAC addresses from the browser"_. Maybe you're trying to reinvent the wheel (poorly), it would really help if you gave your question a little more context. Why aren't any of the available answers a solution to your original problem?

Comment: simple. i'm beginner and i'm trying to create simple unique visitor counter for a simple purpose for the first time and later develop that if necessary. i can copy others code but some of them have mentioned that they are not sure about the performance.

Comment: Where is "How can I uniquely identify a client machine" (php)?  already answered well on SO? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.74.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.2 Safari/537.74.9
```

This is my current user agent. There's nothing in there that's specific to my personal system. Anyone with the same OS with the same browser version will have this same user agent string.

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

For example, this is my current user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36
```

The components of this string are as follows:

- `Mozilla/5.0`: Previously used to indicate compatibility with the Mozilla rendering engine
- `(X11; Linux i686)`: Details of the system in which the browser is running
- `AppleWebKit/531.21.10`: The platform the browser uses
- `(KHTML, like Gecko)`: Browser platform details
- `Chrome/32.0.1700.102`: Information about the browser.

In short, there's in the above user agent string that's really unique to me. If a different person on the Internet with the same configuration accesses your website, then their user agent will be the same.

See [`RFC2616`](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) for more information about the structure of User-Agent strings.